# Problem with ropsten

Tags: ropsten

I have a problem with Ropsten.
I want to send a smart contract on Ropsten with the command **"migrate --reset --network ropsten"** but it does not work.

I get this message:
**Everything is up to date, there is nothing to compile.**

Do you know how to handle this problem?

Thank you very much

Take care

Pierre

Answer (score 0):

You should quit the truffle develop，Then execute the following command：

`truffle compile -all`

`truffle migrate --reset --network ropsten`

If this still doesn't work, make some changes to your contract, such as adding a space.You can try, and God bless you!

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer :)